# What does RtlRestoreContext do when ExceptionCode is STATUS_UNWIND_CONSOLIDATE?

Tags: c++, 64-bit, seh

I'm trying to understand how C++ exception handling is implemented on x64 by Visual C++ runtime.

Upon reading the Nynaeve blog on SEH implementation on x64 at http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=110, it seems that RtlUnwindEx calls RtlRestoreContext with the ExceptionCode set to STATUS_UNWIND_CONSOLIDATE for frame consolidation unwinds.

What is not completely clear to me is what does RtlRestoreContext do then? MSDN states at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/site/ms680605 that "RtlRestoreContext consolidates the call frames between its frame and the frame specified in the context record before calling the callback function. This hides frames from any exception handling that might occur in the callback function."

What is meant by "consolidates the call frames between its frame and the frame specified in the context record"? How does this "hide frames from any exception handling that might occur in the callback function"? What does "frame consolidation" mean and where exactly is the frame being consolidated?

Lets say a C++ catch handler is to be called by RtlRestoreContext, and it throws another exception - is that (re)thrown exception protected by some kind of SEH block? OR, this frame consolidation business somehow takes care of it? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the function, you will see in the circumstances you are referring to, the code sets up a fake machine frame on the stack (relative to [r8] with only RIP and RSP filled) from the *original* context passed to RtlRestoreContext. It then copies the original context into stack space allocated below the machine frame.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ck9asaa9.aspx for more information on the machine frame (under UWOP_PUSH_MACHFRAME).

```
0:004> u ntdll!RtlRestoreContext+0x296
00000000`771f0c05 83ec30          sub     esp,30h
00000000`771f0c08 4c8bc4          mov     r8,rsp
00000000`771f0c0b 4881ecd0040000  sub     rsp,4D0h
00000000`771f0c12 488bf1          mov     rsi,rcx
00000000`771f0c15 488bfc          mov     rdi,rsp
00000000`771f0c18 b99a000000      mov     ecx,9Ah
00000000`771f0c1d f348a5          rep movs qword ptr [rdi],qword ptr [rsi]
00000000`771f0c20 488b842498000000 mov     rax,qword ptr [rsp+98h]
0:004> u
ntdll!RtlRestoreContext+0x2ba:
00000000`771f0c28 49894018        mov     qword ptr [r8+18h],rax
00000000`771f0c2c 488b8424f8000000 mov     rax,qword ptr [rsp+0F8h]
00000000`771f0c34 498900          mov     qword ptr [r8],rax
00000000`771f0c37 488bca          mov     rcx,rdx
00000000`771f0c3a eb12            jmp     ntdll!RcFrameConsolidation (00000000`771f0c4e)
```

Code jumps to the pseudo function the blog is talking about, NTDLL!RcFrameConsolidation.

If we examine the function table and UNWIND entries for this function, we see that it contains the metadata that corresponds to the fake stack frame setup:

```
0:004>.fnent ntdll!rcframeconsolidation

...snip...

Unwind info at 00000000`772c8e0c, 52 bytes
  version 1, flags 0, prolog 0, codes 27
  00: offs 0, unwind op 8, op info f    UWOP_SAVE_XMM128 FrameOffset: 290 reg: xmm15.
  02: offs 0, unwind op 8, op info e    UWOP_SAVE_XMM128 FrameOffset: 280 reg: xmm14.
  04: offs 0, unwind op 8, op info d    UWOP_SAVE_XMM128 FrameOffset: 270 reg: xmm13.
  06: offs 0, unwind op 8, op info c    UWOP_SAVE_XMM128 FrameOffset: 260 reg: xmm12.
  08: offs 0, unwind op 8, op info b    UWOP_SAVE_XMM128 FrameOffset: 250 reg: xmm11.
  0a: offs 0, unwind op 8, op info a    UWOP_SAVE_XMM128 FrameOffset: 240 reg: xmm10.
  0c: offs 0, unwind op 8, op info 9    UWOP_SAVE_XMM128 FrameOffset: 230 reg: xmm9.
  0e: offs 0, unwind op 8, op info 8    UWOP_SAVE_XMM128 FrameOffset: 220 reg: xmm8.
  10: offs 0, unwind op 8, op info 7    UWOP_SAVE_XMM128 FrameOffset: 210 reg: xmm7.
  12: offs 0, unwind op 8, op info 6    UWOP_SAVE_XMM128 FrameOffset: 200 reg: xmm6.
  14: offs 0, unwind op 4, op info f    UWOP_SAVE_NONVOL FrameOffset: f0 reg: r15.
  16: offs 0, unwind op 4, op info e    UWOP_SAVE_NONVOL FrameOffset: e8 reg: r14.
  18: offs 0, unwind op 4, op info d    UWOP_SAVE_NONVOL FrameOffset: e0 reg: r13.
  1a: offs 0, unwind op 4, op info c    UWOP_SAVE_NONVOL FrameOffset: d8 reg: r12.
  1c: offs 0, unwind op 4, op info 7    UWOP_SAVE_NONVOL FrameOffset: b0 reg: rdi.
  1e: offs 0, unwind op 4, op info 6    UWOP_SAVE_NONVOL FrameOffset: a8 reg: rsi.
  20: offs 0, unwind op 4, op info 5    UWOP_SAVE_NONVOL FrameOffset: a0 reg: rbp.
  22: offs 0, unwind op 4, op info 3    UWOP_SAVE_NONVOL FrameOffset: 90 reg: rbx.
  24: offs 0, unwind op 1, op info 0    UWOP_ALLOC_LARGE FrameOffset: 4d0.
  26: offs 0, unwind op a, op info 0    UWOP_PUSH_MACHFRAME.
```

The effect of this is to ‘trick’ the VirtualUnwindEx/exception handling code into thinking the function described by the ContextRecord is the immediate caller of RtlRestoreContext.

From VirtualUnwind's perspective, the callstack is OriginalContext -> RtlRestoreContext -> [user supplied callback], with nothing in between.

Thus, if the stack is ‘unwound’ all of the intermediate frames in between the frame described by ContextRecord and the current context in RtlRestoreContext are ‘forgotten’. i.e. the frames have been consolidated into a single frame that is unwound as a single function.
Thus, if an exception occurs inside the callback function passed in ExceptionRecord, any exception handlers in those intermediate frames are hidden.
As the blog points out, this functionality is largely useful for language exception handling.

As the MS documentation also points out, the locals of the intermediate stack frames are not destroyed prior to calling the callback, which is useful if an exception object in some language was allocated on that function's stack frame.

Answer (score 0):

See

**Figure 6 Unwinding from an Exception** in http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0197/exception/exception.aspx

May be that it what meant by "consolidation"